# Cybersource - not able to catch Microform fields error

Tags: angular, cybersource

There is a MicroformError class described in the [Cybersource documentation](https://developer.cybersource.com/docs/cybs/en-us/digital-accept-flex/developer/all/rest/digital-accept-flex/microform-integ-v2/api-reference-v2/class-microform-error-v2.html)

However, I can only catch the errors that occur during token creation (the error is returned in the callback function)

```
microform.createToken(options, function(err, token) {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
    console.error(err);
    ...
} else {
    ...
   }
 });
});
```

I cannot catch other errors mentioned in the [Cybersource documentation](https://developer.cybersource.com/docs/cybs/en-us/digital-accept-flex/developer/all/rest/digital-accept-flex/microform-integ-v2/api-reference-v2/class-microform-error-v2.html)

The documentation mentions the 'error' event in some places, but in others not:

- [Microform Events](https://developer.cybersource.com/docs/cybs/en-us/digital-accept-flex/developer/all/rest/digital-accept-flex/microform-integ-v2/events-v2.html) (error event not mentioned)
- Part of PDF documentation:

[image: pdf documentation]

I've tried to subscribe to the 'error' event using something like:

```
field.on('error', (data: any) => console.log(data));
```

```
field.on('error', () => console.log('error occured'));
```

but none of them worked.

Do you know if it's possible to catch this kind of error?

PS. I'm doing it in an Angular app